# сортировка по вычисляемому столбцу связанной таблицы gridview в yii2

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

Есть модель изображения. У изображения может быть много оценок от пользователей

```
public function getGalleryRatings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(GalleryRating::className(), ['image_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Средний рейтинг картинки получаю так

```
public function getAverageRating() {
    $avRating = 0;
    if (!empty($this->galleryRatings)) {
        foreach ($this->galleryRatings as $rating) {
            $avRating += $rating->value;
        }
        $avRating = round($avRating / count($this->galleryRatings), 2);
    }
    return $avRating;
}
```

и далее использую этот `getter` при выводе `grid` как один из столбцов

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    ...
    'columns' => [
        ...
        'averageRating',
```

Вопрос. Как реализовать сортировку в `gridview` по этому столбцу? Понимаю, что нужно что-то вероятно прописывать в `GalleryImageSearch` и как-то использовать `GROUP BY`, но не знаю, как.
Также интересно было бы узнать насчет фильтрации по такому столбцу

Comment: Может вам стоит считать среднее арифметическое  sql функцией AVG (http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Group_by_functions.html)? Если же вам не подходит данное решение попробуйте использовать функцию usort (http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) для сортировки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1 (предпочтительный):
А что мешает в таблицу изображений добавить поле `averageRating` и выставлять его в методе `GalleryRating::beforeSave()`, `GalleryRating::beforeDelete()`.

Оценка выставляется 1 раз, а рейтинг будет отображатся в десятки раз больше.

Вариант 2:

```
class Image extends ActiveRecord {
    public $averageRating;
}

Image::find()
    ->select([
        Image::tableName() . '.*',
        'averageRating' => 'AVG(' . GalleryRating::tableName() . '.value)'
    ])
    ->joinWith('galleryRatings', false)
    ->groupBy([Image::tableName() . '.id'])
    // ...
    ->all()
```